# Adding a class based on background image name with javasript

Tags: javascript, html, css-selectors

Now I have `div` created with javascript this divs have a background image with a different image, I need to add a class name to each div based on background image name, Is there a way to do this in javascript or jquery?

```
// adding divs to mapContainer
var mapCont = document.getElementById("mapContainer");
for (var i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
var child = document.createElement("div");
child.classList.add("logo-" + i);
mapCont.appendChild(child)
}
```

css

```
#mapContainer > div.logo-3 {
    background-image: url(../images/car.png);
}
#mapContainer > div.logo-4 {
    background-image: url(../images/bike.png);
}
#mapContainer > div.logo-5 {
    background-image: url(../images/train.png);
}
```

How to add a class name to each div with the same background image name in javascript without the image extension so the divs have another class with the name of background image?

Comment: What do you want? To have created classes with the name of the image on bg?

Comment: Yes exactly this what I need

Answer (score 0):

If i understood your question correctly, you can get the image path from the CSS class using the following code:

```
var body = document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0];
var elem = document.createElement("div");
elem.classList.add('logo-3');
body.appendChild(elem);
alert(getComputedStyle(elem).getPropertyValue('background-image'));
body.removeChild(elem);
```

It will alert the background-image style. Use the contents to add it to your classList. You might want to get the path with a regex.

Make sure to add the element to the DOM to get the properties, otherwise it will return null.